# Adding Particles.js into DIVI theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, particles

Im having troubles with adding JS particles.js "adding Particles.js" into DIVI them which can be found [here](http://www.c-parity.com/CP/tester/)  
([particleJs](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/))Even i add HTML,CSS,JS the result cant be seen, thank you for reply.

Comment: Your particles.js file is not found. Add it to http://c-parity.com/CP/tester/particles.js

Answer (score 0):

I would enqueuer the scripts in functions.php, also before updating this I would create a child theme and add a functions.php file to your child theme and make the changes there to ensure you don't loose the change come updating the theme

Creating a child theme -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
Encuing scripts -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but for the sake of future generations - there is an easy way using the following WP-Plugin [ParticleJs-WP-Plugin](https://github.com/munirkamal/ParticleJs-WP-Plugin) that is available form Github only. This plugin allows you to use the Particle.js JSON via copy&paste. 
The first argument of the function is your ID-name that you can use in the divi builder CSS-section.

```
particlesJS('your-particle-css-id',{});
```

Of course you can as well make a child theme and enque the scripts in functions.php but the plugin does it all for you and is very lightweight.